# Can't access troubleshoot menu

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to get an unsigned driver installed. To do so, I understand you need to get into advanced start-up. I can get into it just fine, however, I don't see the Troubleshoot option, I only get Continue and Turn off your PC. Is there a flag somewhere that has been disabled or something? My google-fu has failed me on this so I've come to you guys for help.

Comment: What is "advanced start-up"??

Comment: Go to "Change PC Settings" -> "General" -> scroll down and you'll see the restart button to access it.

Comment: Can't find anything that disables the troubleshoot option. There are some references to BitLocker stopping entry to Startup options. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode Have you tried other methods like F8 on power up or shutdown /r /o /t 0 command?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried all of the options I can find and no luck. I am not using BitLocker either so I am not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what "Advanced Startup" is, but try opening the Charms (Windows + C) and selecting "Power" then, while holding <Shift>, click "Restart".  Does that get you where you want to be?

Comment: Also tried that. I get the menu just fine, it just doesn't have the troubleshoot option.